# Accumulator with decay?

Tags: signal-analysis, filter-design, math

I am using an accumulator in the form of
X + [Y-1], X plus the unit delay of the output.
Is there an accumulator that follows this form, but will fall to 0 over time, similar to a differentiator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *leaky accumulator* (in analogy with a [leaky integrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_integrator)):

$$y(n)=\alpha x(n)+(1-\alpha)y(n-1),\quad 0<\alpha<1\tag{1}$$

You could also just multiply $y(n-1)$ with a constant less than 1. The reason why in (1) $x(n)$ is multiplied by $\alpha$ is to guarantee a DC gain of 1.